# Can launch Spring Boot from Eclipse (STS) but not from CLI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem that I can't seem to resolve. I have no issues starting a Spring Boot application from Eclipse (Oxygen) with STS 3.9.2, from the Boot Dashboard: 
[image]

However, when I try to run it from command line, I get an error that files are missing:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException:
>   sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy   at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
>     at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)    at
>   java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446)   at
>   org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.(AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:134)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:708)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:357)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
>     at se.itab.bos.admin.AdminServer.main(AdminServer.java:37)  ... 6
>   more

I tried commenting out the following from my startup class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({
//    AppConfig.class
//    , ActiveMqServerConfig.class
//    , MetricConfig.class
//    , AdminConfig.class
//    , SystemConfig.class
//    , SystemMessageRouterConfig.class
//    , CommandConfig.class
//    , AdminMessageRouterConfig.class
})
public class AdminServer {
```

This solves the issue so that I can launch from command line, but I don't understand why. In my pom.xml I have every other module defined, in which these files are contained.

I am using Spring Boot Starter 1.3.5.RELEASE and Java 8.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*UPDATED*

This is my full pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>se.bos</groupId>
            <artifactId>bos-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <relativePath>../bos-parent</relativePath>
        </parent>
        <artifactId>bos-admin</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>BOS Admin</name>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.7</java.version>
            <start-class>se.bos.admin.AdminServer</start-class>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- operations: spring boot -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- operations: spring boot admin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- application: bos -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>bos-site</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>bos-server</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>bos-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>bos-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>bos-model</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>bos-system</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- application: spring boot -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- test -->
            <!-- -->
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>true</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

To start the project from command line, I run:

```
mvn clean install
java -jar target/admin.jar
```

After commenting out each import one by one, I also found that the problem stems from imported modules, but have not yet found why.

Running `java -version` from command line:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

This is the same as what is used in Eclipse and what is in `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Could you please post whole pom so that one can see which other dependencies are being used?
PS: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10441 might be helpful

Comment: Also, I would go commenting out classes one by one to see which exactly one is causing the problem.

Comment: Is the Java installation version that Eclipse uses to run your Spring boot application the exact same as the one your command line uses? Also what command are you running on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Using `mvn clean install` will not produce the executable jar file for you, as this will not package the executable spring boot libraries and pom dependencies. It will only produce a jar file containing only your code.

Using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` you need to execute the `spring-boot:repackage` goal and phase in order for the executable jar file to be appropriately packaged with the spring boot/pom dependencies and ready to be executed on the command line. i.e. run `mvn package spring-boot:repackage` and then run your application on the command line.

Full details on this can be found in the [Spring Boot Maven Plugin Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) and the [spring-boot:repackage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html) goal.

Note: It works in Eclipse because Eclispe has setup your classpath appropriately to reference the dependencies in your pom at compile and runtime, whereas your compiled jar file does not.